# holes in an electronic circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, electronics, electrical-engineering, design

Many times, by looking at electronics circuits I noticed that they have like small holes printed in yhem. The question I want to ask is, what s the purpose of these holes?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_dividers_and_directional_couplers#/media/File%3AMicrostrip_Sawtooth_Directional_Coupler.jpg

Comment: It s like in this image... Why are there holes there?

Comment: This should be asked in the [electronic engineering SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It should. But some of them are needed for screws - btw square holes where additional things to carry round screws are known as bosses - but I believe that a hole could be a good idea even without a screw. One saves some material and makes it possible to attach things or send a wire through it, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The regular spacing and sheer amount of holes in that image is a bit unusual, but I nevertheless suspect that most or all of them are [vias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Via_%28electronics%29): holes drilled through multiple layers of the PCB and plated with copper on the inside to provide an electrical connection between layers. A large number of regularly spaced vias in contiguous planes may be used to spread the current path and therefore also the heat profile between two layers.